# How can I find the positions of something in an ArrayList in a nested loop?

Tags: java, arraylist

is there a way to compare two arrayLists to see if either of them have equal values at any point? I know that I can use two nested loops, however I am trying to do this in log(n) time, so instead, I am trying to do it similarly to how one would merge two lists in mergesort, however I can't really figure out exactly how to implement it. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!
Edit: Yeah I meant nlog(n), not log(n), sorry

Comment: Do you want to find `if` they have equal elements or `which` elements are equal?

Comment: I need to know the position that the elements are equal at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it in `O(log(n))`.

You can implement this with `O(n*log(n))` by first sorting both list and then comparing them element-wise (sorting takes `nlogn` and comparing `n`)

You can do it like this:

1. create to variables `i, j` initialized with 0
2. loop over the lists and compare `l1.get(i)` with `l2.get(j)`

3a. equal: increment both `i, j` (and maybe memorize the tuple)

3b. element of l1 is smaller than the element of l2: increment i only

3c. element of l1 is greater than the element of l2: increment j only

4. exit loop, if one index is out of bounds

You don't need to scan the list for the index that was not out of bounds, since you are just interested in the equal values.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question, I meant l1.get(i).equals(l2.get(j)) for some i,j (the second thing). I figured out how to sort them already, but how exactly would I compare them element-wise?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare whether the values are the same at any point (ie, object at index 1 of list 1 == object at index 1 of list 2) then you'd just loop over the lists and compare (O(N))

If you want to find out whether they have any values in common, sort both and walk down the lists. O (n log n), because of the sorting.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question, I meant the second thing. I know it must be really simple and I can't see it, but how would I walk down the lists in O(nlogn) time?

Comment: Once the lists are sorted (assuming that the items you're comparing are comparable) you eliminate the need to examine all of list 2 for each item in list 1. Consider a small example {1,4,2,67,3} {9,5,2,3,4} - when they're not sorted, you have to examine each item in list2 to see if it's 1, then again to see if it's 4, etc. On the other hand, if they're sorted, you look at the first item in list 2. It's greater than 1, so keep your pointer there. Then look at it again to see if it's 2. It is, so a match. Advance the pointer and look at the next item to see if it's 4, etc. Linear time.

Answer (score 0):

if both list are of same size then

```
for(int i =0; i<listOne.size();i++) {
  int index = listTwo.indexOf(listOne.get(i));
  if(index !=-1) {
    System.out.println("equal at listOne[" + i + "] and listTwo[" +  index + "]");
  }
}
```

Comment: This is O(n^2) because indexOf() is O(n)

Answer (score 0):

What about Heap? Then just merge that heaps.